# Arrhenius equation in Kinetics and Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics

It is always stressed that one should never mix Kinetics with Thermodynamic. How is it then possible to calculate the free energy of activation with the Arrhenius equation? As I understood, the Arrhenius equation and thus the activation energy of a reaction "belongs" to kinetics, whereas the free energy represents a term of Thermodynamics.

An example of the calculation I refer to can be found on page 7 of this link:
http://cbc.arizona.edu/classes/bioc460/summer/460web/lecture/EnzIntrod_11.pdf

Comment: Free energy of activation ( = free energy of TS minus free energy of reactants) is still a kinetic concept. Compare this with free energy of reaction which is free energy of products minus free energy of reactants - that is a thermodynamic concept.